# $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are positive real numbers, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 1$, to find the minimum value of:

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^5}{s - x_i}$$

with $$s = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$

I used Cauchy Schwarz inequality:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^5}{s - x_i})(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{s-x_i}{x_i}) \geq 1$$

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^5}{s - x_i})\geq \frac1{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{s-x_i}{x_i} }$$

the denominator is $$s \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{x_i} - n$$

i don't know a good way to limit it above

Comment: Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: it is an option, but there must be a cooler (faster) way

Comment: LM seem pretty cool to me, especially when, like here, there is no boundary case. Did you try this "option"?

Comment: Suggestion:  Test it for $n=2$, then it becomes a simple calc 1 optimization problem.   That should give you a clue as to what the answer should be.

Comment: I didn't, too many derivatives and the sistem to solve would take much time (I guess), I will try for n = 2

Comment: By [Titu's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/) we have:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i^5}{s-x_i} \geq \frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{\left(x_1^{5/2}+\ldots+x_n^{5/2}\right)^2}{(x_1+\ldots+x_n)}. $$

Comment: for n=2 I believe the minnimum is 2

Comment: Just an idea. We can perhaps use the symmetry in $x_k$ under all possible permutations and conclude somehow that "something interesting" happens when all $x_k$ are equal or on the boundary when some of $x_k$ is zero. But the later becomes the same (symmetric) problem for lower dimensions.

Comment: @onlyme For $n=2$ the minimum is $1/2$ for $x_1=x_2=1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: yes, I found the y and x but forgot to take the inverse, maybe one can use induction to prove it is $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: *Conjecture*: the minimum is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ at $x_1=\ldots=x_n=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: induction is not easy because of the sum on the denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:  Using CS and Power Mean inequalities 
$$LHS \cdot \sum x_i(s-x_i)\ge \left(\sum x_i^3\right)^2\ge \frac1n$$
Further $\sum x_i(s-x_i)=s^2-1\le n-1$, so LHS $\ge \dfrac1{n(n-1)}$, with equality when all the $x_i=\frac1{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: (+1) I used Jensen's Inequality to show that $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3 \ge\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^{3/2}$$ which, when squared, is the same inequality.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let's use the LM

$$F(x_1,...,x_n,\lambda) = (x_1 + ... + x_n)(\frac{1}{x_1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n}) - \lambda(x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 - 1)$$

we must have $$\nabla F = \vec 0$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = (\frac{1}{x_1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n}) + (x_1 + ... + x_n)\frac{-1}{x_i^2} - 2\lambda x_i = 0$$

I am convinced that this is not a good aproach

Comment: How is the first part of this function F related to the method of Lagrange multipliers applied to the function in your question?

Comment: what first part ? The definition ? It is the denominator I got from Cauchy

Comment: The first part $$(x_1 + ... + x_n)(\frac{1}{x_1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n})$$